# CLion Code Completion doesn't work when putting header files in "include" directory

Tags: c++, makefile, include

I have a project with a directory structure like this:

```
LuftOS/
   kernel/
      include/
         Bitmap.h
      src/
         Bitmap.cpp
         Kernel.cpp
   Makefile
```

In the past, I had `Bitmap.h` inside of `kernel/src/`, but I decided to put all of my header files in `kernel/include/`. In my Makefile, I added a `-I./include/` to the compiler flags so everything works and compiles fine. (I use the command line to compile since this is a OS dev project, I only use CLion for editing)

However, now CLion doesn't seem to detect `Bitmap.h` and code completion won't work. Googling it tells me CLion needs me to use CMake so that it can detect the additional include directory or something, but I don't even use CLion for compilation/building so I don't really know what to do.

Comment: It would not be that difficult to switch to use CMake for this if your structure is accurate.

Comment: @drescherjm How would I go about doing that without actually using CMake for compiling/building? I don't want to use CLion's "Run" to run the VM for my OS, I just want CLion's code completion to work.